# hfill – Too long content before \hfill breaks right alignment

Tags: formatting, alignment, hfill

I have a list where each item has a number of points assigned to it, which should be in the same row on the right side. This works very well in almost all cases with `\hfill`. However, if the line becomes too long and there is no more space for the number of points, it is moved to the next line but not right-justified, but left-justified.
Is there a way to keep this for all points, independent of the length of the line, always on the right side?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{libertine}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item blablabla \hfill 1~P
    \item Beschreiben Sie ausführlich eine Maßnahme zur Förderung der Gesundheit in der Kita\hfill 3~P
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `\hspace*{\fill}` instead of `\hfill`. Moreover, I'd pack the formatting into a macro, just in case you have to adjust the formatting. Put

```
\newcommand\Punkte[1]{\unskip\hspace*{\fill}~#1~P}
```

into the preamble and use it as

```
... Gesundheit in der Kita\Punkte{3}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{libertine}
\newcommand\Punkte[1]{\unskip\hspace*{\fill}~#1~P}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item blablabla\Punkte{1}
    \item Beschreiben Sie ausführlich eine Maßnahme zur Förderung der Gesundheit in der Kita\Punkte{3}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for this well working solution :)

Comment: @simande So if your students come across your post, they will know that they should learn about health in daycare centers when preparing for the test ;-)

Comment: If my students would come across my post – on a board like this one – I would be the happiest teacher in the world :D